# datetime.strptime extracting from dataframe: error

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, pandas

Strptime doesn't do what I (starting Python data-scientist) want it to do. I've got a data file formatted as follows:

```
STN,YYYYMMDD,HH,RH
210,20121001,1,0
210,20121001,2,0
210,20121001,3,0
210,20121001,4,0
...
```

In the second column the dates, in the third the hour (1-24) of an observation. I'd like to get the date and time in a datetime format to merge it with other data. My try:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

meteo = pd.read_csv("x:\\hourly.txt", parse_dates=[[1,2]])
# dataframe created with a column 'YYYYMMDD_HH'
meteo['datetime']=meteo['YYYYMMDD_HH'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d %H'))
```

Python crashes on the last line with a (for me) very cryptic error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    meteo['datetime']=meteo['YYYYMMDD_HH'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d %H'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1998, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "inference.pyx", line 1016, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:53184)
  File "X:\test.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    meteo['datetime']=meteo['YYYYMMDD_HH'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d %H'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help in advance, 
Niels

Comment: I would try and print that value and see how it looks... it looks like you either have extra letters in your strptime pattern or in your value ... you can probably forcibly limit the size of x to resolve the issue but Im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive debugging I solved the problem myself....The datafile contains hours from 1..24. Parsing raises an error when the hour is *24*. It accepts hours from 0..23. I guess I have to reformat the datafile first!

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the columns when you read the CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H')
df = pd.read_csv("time.csv", parse_dates = [['YYYYMMDD', 'HH']], date_parser=parse)

print df
```

Output:

```
          YYYYMMDD_HH  STN  RH
0 2012-10-01 01:00:00  210   0
1 2012-10-01 02:00:00  210   0
2 2012-10-01 03:00:00  210   0
3 2012-10-01 04:00:00  210   0
```